# I guess it renders without data, how can I fix it?

Tags: node.js, express

codes and error are below. This error sometimes gives for different models.
I tried using async and await but couldn't figure it out.
I did a lot of research on what to do, but I could not reach the result. When I refresh the page the data comes in but seeing this error is very annoying.

```
const aboutModel = require("../models/aboutModel");
const skillModel = require("../models/skillsModel");
const socialMediaModel = require("../models/socialMediaModel");
const educationModel = require("../models/educationModel");
const experienceModel = require("../models/experienceModel");

const index = (req, res) => {
    aboutModel.findOne({}, (err, datas) => {
        aboutDatas =  datas;
        if(err){
            console.log("hata");
        }
    });
    skillModel.findOne({}, (err, datas) => {
        skillDatas =  datas;
        if(err){
            console.log("Hata");
        }
    });
    socialMediaModel.findOne({}, (err, datas) => {
        socialMediaDatas =  datas;
        if(err){
            console.log("hata");
        }
    });
    educationModel.find({}, (err, datas) => {
        educationDatas = datas;
        if(err){
            console.log("Hata");
        }
    });
    experienceModel.find({}, (err, datas) => {
        experienceDatas =  datas;
        if(err){
            console.log("hata");
        }
    });
res.render("index", {about: aboutDatas, socialMedia: socialMediaDatas, skills: skillDatas, education: educationDatas, experience: experienceDatas});
}

module.exports = {
    index
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8gyd2.png)

Comment: Where did you define `aboutDatas` and other similar variables?

Comment: res.render wont wait for all them callbacks to resolve

Comment: Are `.findOne()` and `.find()` MongoDB operations?  Do they return Promises that can be `await`-ed if you don't supply a callback?

Comment: In order to reach it globally, I made a seamless definition within the object. The problem is that the render does not wait for the data to arrive.How can I make the render wait for the data?

Answer (score 0):

As the error indicates you haven't defined your variables.

```
const index = (req, res) => {
  // you must define your variables.
  let aboutDatas, skillDatas, socialMediaDatas, educationDatas, 
  experienceDatas;

    aboutModel.findOne({}, (err, datas) => {
        aboutDatas =  datas;
        if(err){
            console.log("hata");
        }
    });
    skillModel.findOne({}, (err, datas) => {
        skillDatas =  datas;
        if(err){
            console.log("Hata");
        }
    });
    socialMediaModel.findOne({}, (err, datas) => {
        socialMediaDatas =  datas;
        if(err){
            console.log("hata");
        }
    });
    educationModel.find({}, (err, datas) => {
        educationDatas = datas;
        if(err){
            console.log("Hata");
        }
    });
    experienceModel.find({}, (err, datas) => {
        experienceDatas =  datas;
        if(err){
            console.log("hata");
        }
    });
res.render("index", {about: aboutDatas, socialMedia: socialMediaDatas, skills: skillDatas, education: educationDatas, experience: experienceDatas});
}
```

Comment: in findone aboutDatas = datas; It doesn't define it that way. Outside the function, aboutDatas is undefined. Data comes in the function, but when I define aboutDatas, it cannot access aboutData from outside and sends undefined in render.

Comment: my problem: 
In order to reach it globally, I made a seamless definition within the object. The problem is that the render does not wait for the data to arrive.How can I make the render wait for the data?